Musetips Mp3 editor and cutter not working after Windows 11 Feb and March Update
Musetips Mp3 cutter and editor getting stuck on loading screen.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the program several times.
http://www.musetips.com/free-mp3-cutter-and-editor.html
What should I do? Would only uninstalling the updates or anything else to make this program work? If so? How do I do that safely? Or any other option to make the program work?(Would not like to use any other mp3 editors)

Doesn't happen for me. Did you download the latest version?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


What version? Latest is 2.8  2. Have you tried both portable and installed versions?


What does Event Viewer say? Are there any logs?
